# Open telemetry with Prisma does not extract query params

Tags: prisma, open-telemetry, prisma2, open-telemetry-collector

I am using Prisma and trying to send data regarding my query to my exporter (very basic).
When the processor receives the spans, it does not contain the actual query parameter values (only $1, $2, etc..).

```html
{
  traceId: '143935679dd6ce6820615153508f1dda',
  parentId: '2a4ae27990ead0fb',
  traceState: undefined,
  name: 'prisma:engine:db_query',
  id: 'ca3725f6db13db48',
  kind: 0,
  timestamp: 1706011446653329,
  duration: 16392,
  attributes: {
    'db.statement': `SELECT "public"."Photo"."id", "public"."Photo"."description", "public"."Photo"."filename", "public"."Photo"."views", "public"."Photo"."isPublished" FROM "public"."Photo" WHERE ("public"."Photo"."id" = $1 AND "public"."Photo"."description" = $2) LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4 /* traceparent='00-143935679dd6ce6820615153508f1dda-1a2dc9debddf0d4c-01' */`
  },
  status: { code: 0 },
  events: [],
  links: []
}
```

I am using `PrismaInstrumentation` and `SimpleSpanProcessor`.

how can I get the parameters? it that possible without using any custom decorator on the method invoking the query?